# Can I Authenticate my Web Api against several OpenID Connect Servers?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am using IdentityServer4 (OpenID Connect/OAuth2 Server) to protect MyApi. The Client is a desktop client (exe). It is no browser. I use the following workflow to request MyApi (https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html).

1. The Client sends his credentials to the IdentyServer4 which returns a token
2. The Client uses the token as the BearerToken
3. The Client requests MyApi with the BearerToken
4. MyApi knows the address of the IdentityServer4 and verifies the token. After that it sends back some data.

Is it possible that MyApi works with multiple different IdentityServer4 (OpenID Connect/OAuth2 Servers) instances?

I mean if I open my browser and login to Stackoverflow I can choose different Login-Providers. I mean the browser handles the redirecting. Is there similar Workflow if I have a exe/desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you mention with StackOverflow and different login options - these are external providers. You can add them to IdentityServer, but then you will have only one instance, with different providers.

Just from curiosity - why you want to have 2 instances of IdentityServer? Is this really what you want, or you want different authentication providers? If so - then you need to follow [this](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html), but you need different flow there (not client_credentials).

For the `exe` scenario - you can use [OidcClient](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient2), but it will still require user login, if using any kind of external authentication (like Google, Facebook etc. other OpenID providers)

Comment: If I add the second IdentityServer IDS2 I get the following Exception when starting up the server: 
"Scheme already exists: BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt".
Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I edited my answer - second IDS is not your solution.